# Akka stream - List to mapAsync of individual elements

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

My stream has a Flow whose outputs are List[Any] objects. I want to have a mapAsync followed by some other stages each of which processed an individual element instead of the list. How can I do that?

Effectively I want to connect the output of

```
Flow[Any].map { msg =>
  someListDerivedFrom(msg)
}
```

to be consumed by -

```
Flow[Any].mapAsyncUnordered(4) { listElement =>
  actorRef ? listElement
}.someOtherStuff
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the combinator you are looking for is `mapConcat`.  This combinator will take an input argument and return something that is an `Iterable`.  A simple example would be as follows:

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem()
implicit val mater = ActorMaterializer()

val source = Source(List(List(1,2,3), List(4,5,6)))
val sink = Sink.foreach[Int](println)

val graph =
  source.
    mapConcat(identity).
    to(sink)
graph.run
```

Here, my `Source` is spitting out `List` elements, and my `Sink` accepts the underlying type of what's in those `List`s.  I can't connect them directly together as the types are different.  But if I apply `mapConcat` between them, they can be connected as that combinator will flatten those `List` elements out, sending their individual elements (`Int`) downstream.  Because the input element to `mapConcat` is already an `Iterable`, then you only need to use the `identify` function in the body of `mapConcat` to make things work.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying mapConcat a bit differently and that was not working. What exactly is the significance of "identity".

Comment: _identity_ is defined in _scala.Predef_ and is just what it looks like: a function which transforms something into itself. Very useful for passing as the function required by _map_, _flatMap_, etc.